# Karma does not start from the cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, karma-runner

There is a library [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html).

The version of the Node.js - 0.10.26.

The instructions indicated that the creation of the configuration file on the command line required to execute the command:

```
karma init
```

However, if while executing this command displays the error:

```
"Karma" is not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

In the environment variables in the "Path" Set path to "npm" and to "karma / bin"

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\bin
```

Node.js and Karma reinstalled - does not help

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you install it globally using `npm install -g karma`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved.

For correct operation of "karma", you must install "karma-cli":

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```